Is it possible to preserve matched process output in expect interact?
Consider the following expect script:
#!/usr/bin/expect

spawn bash
interact {
  -o
  hello_world { send "Goodbye" }
}

Under this script, any time the process sends hello_world, the hello_world disappears and turns into Goodbye.
I could explicitly write send_user("hello_world") to bring it back, but I am wondering if there is an option such as -echo for user input that would tell expect to show the process output anyways.

Could you use an example to demo what you want to do?

At this point, it's mostly academic curiosity since I was reading Exploring Expect and noticed the echo flag did not work for messages from process that matched a pattern.

In the future, I could imagine it's a useful teaching tool, to show people what expect is doing without hiding part of the interaction. It's another strange asymmetry that when using the expect function, everything is visible with log_user 1, but there would be no option to make matched patterns visible for the interact function.
